# Deleting more than 157 columns using the .contains() and/or .startswith() function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Good day all,

I am very new in Python and Data Science, and I figured I would get my hands dirty, withi=out waisting any time. I am trying to delete (drop) more than 2
columns/fields in my DataFrame. The .drop() function needs me to insert the 'full name' of the column and that might tall ask, if one must delete over 200
columns.  I would like to use the '.startswith() and/or '.contains() tools. [the lambda option needs the full name of the column(s) - which is a daunting task].
I have used the code below:
My code is as follows:

```
Proc_df = Proc_df.loc[:, ~Proc_df.columns.str.startswith
                      ('KI_2204993', 'KI_9095014','KI_2204943','KI_2783003','KI_9094998','KI_2783004','KI_2783005','KI_2783006',
                       'KI_9094999','KI_9095098','KI_2783007','KI_2205006','KI_2205008','KI_2205016','KI_2205018','KI_2220101',
                       'KI_2220102','KI_2220103','KI_2783022','KI_2220110','KI_2220111','KI_2220113','KI_9095018','KI_9095020',
                       'KI_9095021','KI_9095022','KI_9095023','KI_2220114','KI_9095024','KI_2205042','KI_2205043','KI_2205044',
                       'KI_2205045','KI_2205046','KI_2205047','KI_2205048','KI_2205049','KI_2205050','KI_2205051','KI_2783027',
                       'KI_2205076','KI_2205077','KI_2205078','KI_2205080','KI_2205082','KI_2205083','KI_2205084','KI_2205085',
                       'KI_2205095','KI_2205096','KI_2205097','KI_2205098','KI_2205102','KI_2205104','KI_2205105','KI_2205106',
                       'KI_2205107','KI_2205108','KI_2205109','KI_2205111','KI_2205112','KI_2205114','KI_2205115','KI_2205116',
                       'KI_2205117','KI_2205118','KI_9095025','KI_2783042','KI_2205120','KI_1086818','KI_1086818','KI_1086818',
                       'KI_2205122','KI_2205123','KI_2205124','KI_2205125','KI_2205126','KI_1138362','KI_2205129','KI_9095099',
                       'KI_2205130','KI_2783048','KI_9095028','KI_1138362','KI_6478247','KI_2205136','KI_2205137','KI_2783150',
                       'KI_2205141','KI_2205144','KI_2205145','KI_2205146','KI_2205147','KI_2205148','KI_2205151','KI_2205152',
                       'KI_2205153','KI_2252310','KI_9095029','KI_9095030','KI_9095031','KI_1138362','KI_9095032','KI_2205158',
                       'KI_2205159','KI_9704603','KI_1001 (Please give a br','KI_NumberOfEmployees (How','KI_YearFounded (Which yea',
                       'KI_WomanOwned (Are you Wo','KI_2003 (Are you WBENC (W','KI_2004 (Are you NWBOC (N','KI_2005 (Are you State Go',
                       'KI_2006 (Are you Locality','KI_2007 (Are you self-cer','KI_3004 (Other Certificat','KI_MinorityOwned (Are you',
                       'KI_2009 (Are you NMSDC (N','KI_2010 (Are you Small Bu','KI_2011 (Are you State Go','KI_2012 (Are you Locality',
                       'KI_2013 (Are you self-cer','KI_3005 (Other Certificat','KI_2001 (Are you Small Bu','KI_2015 (Are you Small Bu',
                       'KI_2016 (Are you 8(a) Cer','KI_2017 (Are you HUBZone ','KI_2018 (Are you State Go','KI_2019 (Are you Locality',
                       'KI_2020 (Are you self-cer','KI_3006 (Other Certificat','KI_VeteranOwned (Are you ','KI_DisabledVeteranOwned (',
                       'KI_VietnamVeteranOwned (A','KI_2023 (Are you ISO 9001','KI_2024 (Are you TS 16949','KI_2025 (Are you ISO 1400',
                       'KI_2026 (Are you ISO 2600','KI_2027 (Are you ISO 3100','KI_2028 (Are you ISO 5000','KI_3008 (Are you ISO Comp',
                       'KI_3003 (Primary Capabili','KI_2030 (Green Initiative','KI_UNSPSCCategories (Comm','KI_VatID (VAT Id)',
                       'KI_UsTIN (Tax Id)','KI_StockSymbol (Stock Sym','KI_LegalName (Legal Name)','KI_OrganizationType (Type',
                       'KI_RegionalTIN (Regional ','KI_StateTIN (State Tax Id','KI_BackupWithholdingExemp','KI_StateOfIncorporation (',
                       'KI_GlobalLocationNumber (')]
```

and got this error message:

```
TypeError: wrapper3() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 155 were given
```

#Removing the unwanted columns

#This only allows a maximum is 2 variables [in other words, I can't put more than 2 of these:

```
#df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('Prod')]
#Proc_df = Proc_df.loc[:, ~Proc_df.columns.str.startswith('KI_2783005','KI_2783006')]
```

Comment: thank you @Coralien, this works perfectly - it almost like magic. I guess my journey 'officially' begins?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien - thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

Build a regex pattern with your long list and use `str.contains`:

```
import re

columns_to_drop = ['KI_2204993', 'KI_9095014', 'KI_2204943', ...
                   'KI_StateOfIncorporation (', 'KI_GlobalLocationNumber (']
pattern = fr"^(?:{'|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in columns_to_drop)})"

Proc_df = Proc_df.loc[:, ~Proc_df.columns.str.contains(pattern, regex=True)]
```

---

**Old answer**

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
Proc_df = Proc_df.filter(regex=r'^(?!KI_)')
```

Now, `Proc_df` contains columns that don't start with 'KI_'.

If you need also to remove 'Prod':

```
Proc_df = Proc_df.filter(regex=r'^(?!KI_|Prod)')
```

Comment: We can't use 'KI_' because in the same dataframe there other columns that also contain 'KI_', hence I have that long list regarding all the columns' 'starting with' the stated words.

Comment: Also, please assist me in explaining in more detail what the (regex=r'^(?!KI_|Prod)'. My understanding is that 'KI_' and 'Prod' would be the columns (start with words) - I'm not understanding the 'regex=r'^(?!' part?

Comment: @Siyabonga_B. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?